# [PM2][ERROR] Interpreter python is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH. (type 'which python' to double check.)

Tags: python, discord

When I try to run my discord python bot:

`qbasty@cody-discord-bot:~/matrixcraft-cody$ pm2 start Cody.py --interpreter=python`

`[PM2][ERROR] Interpreter python is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH. (type 'which python' to double check.)`

I get that error.
Ubuntu 20 on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 21):

Here is what worked for me :

`pm2 start bot.py --name bot --interpreter python3`